# When we re-build or re-organize index, is it the clustered or non-clustered index?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Over time there is index fragmentation and the pages that hold the index need to be re-organized or re-built. Just curious if this is applicable only to non clustered index? Since this data is stored in pages separate from the pages that hold the main table data.

Or does it also apply to clustered index? (pages that hold the main table data)

Comment: Both traditional clustered and non-clustered indexes are b-tree indexes. All b-tree indexes can have fragmentation and unused space.

Answer (score 0):

You can rebuild or reorganize any index, `custered` or `non-clustered`. You can even rebuild a `heap` starting with `SQL Server 2008`.

It's really not clear WHY this should be related on the type of index...